# Access the value of the TextBlock when it's bound

Tags: windows-phone-7, binding, textblock

I'm working on an app for WP7 but i have this small problem:

```
<TextBlock Name="rName" 
           Text="{Binding LineOne2}" 
           TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
           Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" />
```

I have this `Textblock` binding to `LineOne2`, I set up a tap event to launch another page when it gets tapped.
The problem is, when I try to get the value of that text `rName.Text`, it shows that its unavailable.

So I was wandering is there any possible way to get the value of that `TextBlock` to use it as parameter for a method in another page even if it was binding? Or is there any other way to do so?

My list contains 2 textboxes and an image in a stackpanel.... I need to press in that textbox open a new page with the value of that textbox in that page value and as a parameter to a method.

edit:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items1}" 
         Margin="14,149,8,8" 
         Foreground="#FF7A0100" 
         Grid.RowSpan="2">
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Name="featuredPanel" 
                  Orientation="Horizontal" 
                  Margin="0,0,0,17" 
                  Height="105" 
                  Width="432" 
                  Tap="featuredPanel_Tap">
                  <!--Replace rectangle with image-->
          <Image Height="100" 
                 Width="100" 
                 Source="{Binding ImagePath1}">
          </Image>
          <StackPanel Width="311">
            <TextBlock x:Name="rName" 
                       Text="{Binding LineOne1}" 
                       TextWrapping="NoWrap" 
                       Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LineTwo1}" 
                       TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                       Margin="12,-6,12,0" 
                       Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" />
          </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Also I'm binding data from an XML file.

I need to use the TextBox "rName" to get the value and use it to do a linq query on the xml file to get the addressa and phone number from that XML file and bind them to the Textboxes in the other page.

Comment: Since the `TextBlock.Text` property is bound to `LineOne2` its value should be whatever `LineOne2` is set to. So instead of using `rName.Text` just read the value of the `LineOne2` variable. If that is not working you need to post some additional XAML surrounding this `TextBlock`, for instance, if it is part of a `ListBox`'s `ItemTemplate` you need to show that.

Comment: Well the TextBlock is part of a stackpanel and the stackpanel is part of a ListBox. I'm adding data from an xml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you can't access the `TextBlock` by name is because it is part of a `ListBox`'s `ItemTemplate`.

Think about it, the `ListBox` is going to have as many items as there are elements in the `Items1` collection, so how can you specify which `TextBlock` you're referring to if you're accessing it by name?

There are a couple of different ways to solve this problem. One way is to save the currently tapped item in the `featuredPanel_Tap` handler. Add this line to the handler:

```
var currentItem = ((sender as StackPanel).DataContext) as MyItemType;
```

`MyItemType` is the type of object that is contained in the `Items1` collection. Then you can access the text as `currentItem.LineOne1` or `currentItem.LineTwo1`.

Another way is to create a `TwoWay` binding for the `ListBox`'s `SelectedItem` or `SelectedIndex` property. The bound item would be automatically updated to the correct object within `Items1` when the user taps on a `ListBox` item.

Answer (score 1):

If you are binding you *shouldn't* access the TextBlock directly. However if you want to you can do the following:

#### XAML

```
<TextBlock x:Name="rName" Text="{Binding LineOne2, Mode=TwoWay}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" />
```

#### CodeBehind

```
string text = rName.Text;
string text = LineOne2;
```

either way should work, but you should just access LineOne2 directly

Comment: There's no need for a `TwoWay` binding, it is a `TextBlock`, not a `TextBox`

Comment: I threw it in there in case he throws something that might change it via the Name

Comment: well i need to do you way and i was going to do so, but it doest work. I can't use rName.

Comment: @user1200204 Why wouldn't that work? Perhaps you could post some C# code on what you've tried?

Comment: I did the same as you mentioned, i'm not able to access them no idea:(

Comment: To access this variable or text block you need to be in the code behind. If your not then you need other things in order to access it through objects

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 ways to doing this. One is that you use a global variable. Basically you declare a public variable inside of the app.xaml.cs file and now you have access to it on any page. The second way is to pass it as a parameter in the uri of the page.

Check out this page on [App Hub](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/66396/406173.aspx) for more info.

**Update:** If you need to access the value of the textblock there are two ways of doing that also. Either set the global variable or parameter equal to the property that your binding to in your viewmodel, or if your using the code behind just set it to the Text property of the textblock.